# Is there a decent vector / spline library for php?

Tags: php, image, vector, antialiasing

Does anyone know of the best way to render clean vectors into a php image and then serve it as a jpeg/png?

Specifically I want to draw lines, polygons and splines which are anti-aliased and then serve them up as jpegs. Preferably also with an alpha option when rendering.

What would be spectacular is a php library with a similar API to Raphael (without the animation) - not only because Raphael has a great API but also because I'm already using it on my website for the dynamic bits but also need to bake jpeg's in parallel for static consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagemagick is available for PHP. See the IMagickDraw class (http://php.net/imagick). Btw, AFAIK, there is no alpha option in JPEG, only RGB colors.