# Is there a good PHP library for vectors and matrices?

Tags: php, vector, matrix

I need a PHP library for vectors and matrices. The library I'm looking for should include functions like matrix multiplication, vector cosine similarity, convolution etc.

I also expect such a library to have a proper compact internal representation of sparse vectors and matrices.

I'm using PHP 5.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a decent vector / spline library for php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658105/is-there-a-decent-vector-spline-library-for-php)

Comment: @shamittomar This question does not relate to imagery, therefore it is not a duplicate...

Comment: @shamit: The question you mention asks for an image processing library. Answers to the question you mention do not meet my requirements since I'm actually working on an information retrieval application.

Answer (score 7):

There is

- http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix and
- http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Vector/

and a number of other related PEAR packages about Math

- http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=math&in=packages&x=0&y=0&p=1

I do not know if they suit your needs though. See for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but these libraries don't suit my needs. No sparse vectors, no cosine similarity, no convolution.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a PHP4 port of the [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) matrix library at http://www.phpmath.com but it seems to have disappeared from the site. We use it in PHPExcel (though I've updated it a bit to PHP5)

Answer (score 1):

There is this library:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmatrixlib/

it contains matrix multiply, inverse, transpose and determinant